# How to avoid the need of typing .php on the url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm on MacOs Big Sur, using Apache and PHP. What I want is: not needing to put `.php` on the end of my files to load it.

For instance, instead of typing this on the URL:

```
127.0.0.1/public_html/home.php
```

I want just to type

```
127.0.0.1/public_html/home
```

To achieve this, I'm using this code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex home.php index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The code above works on my hosting, but for some reason, it does not work on my development machine. Instead, a get a 404 error.

[image: 404 Not Found Message]

The `.htaccess` file with the code is on the root of `public_html` folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess file. Could you please do let us know where is your htaccess file present? and where is your php files present in your server?

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase /` line just bellow the `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The .htaccess file is on /public_html, the same folder the script i'm trying to load is.

Comment: @AmitVerma Tried it, but no lucky :-/

Comment: Shouldn't the URL you should request be `http://localhost/home` ?

Comment: Have you previously had anything in your `.htaccess` file? What happens when you request `127.0.0.1/public_html/`? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled?

Comment: @arkascha Does htaccess make difference if i call by the hostname or ip ? Doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: @MrWhite How can i check if the overrides are enabled ?

Comment: If you are on Apache then type some "nonsense" at the top of the file. If you don't get an error then `.htaccess` files are not enabled in the server config.

Comment: That is not what I meant. It is the _path_ component of your URL that matters: `http://127.0.0.1/home` ...

Comment: @MrWhite That was the problem, thank you very much ! Please post as solution, so i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By typing some "nonsense" at the top of the `.htaccess` file and *not* getting an error (ordinarily you would get a 500 Internal Server Error) it would seem that `.htaccess` overrides were not enabled on the server. So, `.htaccess` files were effectively disabled - which they are by default on Apache 2.4.

To enable `.htaccess` overrides (to allow `.htaccess` to override the server config) you need to set the `AllowOverride` directive in the appropriate `<Directory>` container in the server config (or `<VirtualHost>` container). The default on Apache 2.4 is `AllowOverride None`.

With the directives as posted you would need a minimum of:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes Options
```

`FileInfo` for mod_rewrite, `Indexes` for `DirectoryIndex` and `Options` for `Options` and related directives.

Although it is common (and easier) to just set:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
> ```

These directives are not strictly correct. Whilst they may work OK for the URLs you are testing, they would result in a rewrite-loop (500 error response) if you simply append a slash to your URLs (and there is no directory by that name), eg. `/home/` (or `/home/<anything>`). This is because your *condition* that tests for the presence of the `.php` file is not necessarily the same as the URL-path you are rewriting to. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault for a thorough explanation of this issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Also, there's no need to check that the request does not map to a directory to then check if the request + `.php` extension maps to a file. If the request maps to a file then it can not also be a directory, so if the 2nd condition is true, the 1st condition must also be true and is therefore superfluous.

And there's no need to backslash-escape literal dots in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* - this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex.

So, these directives should be written like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

(`RewriteBase` should *not* be used here.)

You can further optimise this by excluding requests that already contain what looks like a file extension (assuming your URLs that need rewriting do not contain a dot near the end of the URL-path). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

(With this 2nd version, it does not matter if `RewriteBase` is set - it is not used.)

> ```
> DirectoryIndex home.php index.php
> ```

You gave an example URL of `/public_html/home` (to which `.php` is appended). However, this `DirectoryIndex` directive allows `home.php` to also be served when simply requesting the directory `/public_html/`. It should be one or the other, not both.