# enable .htaccess support in the apache server configuration

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I get this error when trying to install software

Can not access /install_manager. Common reason for the error is that the .htaccess is not properly working for your web server. Check the web server support for .htaccess and if needed, configure it correctly to remove .php from URLs. Error code: 404

This is my .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The [`AccessFileName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive specifies what per-directory config filename(s) Apache should look for.

Comment: And in addition to that the [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive allows to control what can be configured using such distributed configuration files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid the need of typing .php on the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107516/how-to-avoid-the-need-of-typing-php-on-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by making the following change in the /etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf file, add the following line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I hope it works for you the same way it did for me.

Best regards.

Comment: This would seem to solve a very different problem to the one being asked in the question?!